# How to allocate the array before calling strcpy?

Tags: c, string

Given:

```
char test[] = "bla-bla-bla";
```

Which of the two is more correct?

```
char *test1 = malloc(strlen(test));
strcpy(test1, test);
```

or

```
char *test1 = malloc(sizeof(test));
strcpy(test1, test);
```

Comment: Attention: `strlen(test) != sizeof test`. The difference is 1. The terminating `'\0'` is not counted with `strlen()` but is accounted for with `sizeof`.

Comment: Though sizeof() works in this context I would discourage its use for this type of operation as arrays very easily decay into pointers and unless you are careful you may get caught out by this.

Comment: prefer `strncpy()` over `strcpy()` for memory bounds safety.

Answer (score 28):

This will work on all null-terminated strings, including pointers to `char` arrays:

```
char test[] = "bla-bla-bla";
char *test1 = malloc(strlen(test) + 1);
strcpy(test1, test);
```

You won't get the correct size of the array pointed to by `char*` or `const char*` with `sizeof`. This solution is therefore more versatile.

Comment: strlen(test) + 1. strlen doesn't count the necessary NULL.

Comment: Ok, as you wish. I always use sizeof(type) to have more variable-OS-friendly code.

Comment: @Tomasz: Except `sizeof(char)` is defined as equal to `1` byte. As for the number of *bits* in it, however...

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined by the C standard to always be 1.

Comment: So what is wrong with putting sizeof(char) into the code? It makes it more explicit in what you are trying to do. Thus if the code is ever changed to use wchar_t for example then it would be easier to spot where the code needs to be changed. So: Though not required here I see it as a benefit to include it in the code as it makes the meaning of the code more precise.

Comment: I've strongly argued against writing `sizeof(char)` for years. It adds visual clutter, and the semantics of object size in C have been units of `sizeof(char)` since the beginning. That makes an expression clear and simple in a common case, and calls attention to the dependence on a typed allocation in the other cases.

Comment: @Martin York: Since you are using the return value of `strlen()`, `char` is implied - if you changed to `wchar_t` you would need to change to `wcslen()` anyway.  If you do want to use `sizeof`, I suggest `sizeof test1[0]` (since that will automatically change if you change the type of `test1`).

Comment: Why its working to me without the +1 in the end can some one help me understand?

Answer (score 3):

Neither:

```
#include <string.h>
char *mine = strdup(test);
```

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to the version using `strlen` -- *on the implementations that provide it.* The problem, of course, is that it's an extension, so you can't depend on its presence.

Comment: Of course you can easily write your own `strdup` if it's missing.

Comment: `strdup` is not defined by the Standard. After using it you need to call `free()`, so you must also `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @pmg: You'd need to #include `<stdlib.h>` to use `malloc` so that's kind of a given already.

Comment: @R: Although it's easy, if you write your own `strdup`, you get undefined behavior; names starting with `str` are reserved. Fortunately, it's just as easy to write your one `dupe_string` (or whatever other name you prefer).

Comment: On most good systems, strdup is defined as a weak reference. This means you can override it for your own code. Of course this doesn't make it a good idea, but a quick fix for crappy systems that don't provide it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `strlen`, because `sizeof` will fail silently if you change test to be a run-time defined string. This means that `strlen` is a far safer idea than `sizeof` as it will keep working.

Comment: at run-time the variable also can be uninitialized, strlen/strcpy will crash.

Comment: At least in that case you'd get a crash instead of silently the wrong value. In addition, it's much easier for the compiler to warn you about potential uninitialized variable use. Finally, if you pass an uninitialized variable, it doesn't matter how you determined it's size.

Answer (score 2):

```
char test[]="bla-bla-bla";
char *test1 = malloc(strlen(test) + 1); // +1 for the extra NULL character
strcpy(test1, test);
```

Comment: This answer seems duplicate of [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695263#3695271)

Answer (score 2):

I think `sizeof` is the correct one. Reason behind that is `strlen(str)` will give you length of the string( excluding the terminating null). And if you are using `strcpy`, it actually copy the whole string including the terminating null, so you will allocate one byte less if you use `strlen` in `malloc`. But `sizeof` gives the size of the string pointed by test, including the terminating null, so you will get correct size `malloc` chunk to copy the string including the terminating null.

Comment: sizeof() will return a surprisingly 'wrong' result if you pass a (char *) object to it.  It will return "the number of bytes necessary to store a pointer to 'char'", which is not necessarily equal to the size of the string pointed at by the pointer.

Comment: +1: In the code shown, the `sizeof()` solution is correct and the `strlen()` one is incorrect.  The `sizeof()` solution might over-allocate memory if the string has been shortened since it was created.  However, the definition of the array must be in scope for it to work - so the more generally safe solution uses `strlen(str)+1`, or assumes a POSIX environment and uses `strdup()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) definitely causes UB

2) may cause UB (if `malloc` fails)

I'd go with 2) as there is a better chance of the construct working as intended; or even better I'd write a version that works as intended (without UB) in all situations.

---

**Edit**

- Undefined Behaviour in 1)

  `test1` will have space for the characters in `test`, but not for the terminating `'\0'`. The call to `strcpy()` will try to write a `'\0'` to memory that does not belong to `test1`, hence UB.
- Undefined Behaviour in 2)

  If the call to `malloc()` fails to reserve the requested memory, `test1` will be assigned `NULL`. Passing `NULL` to `strcpy()` invokes UB.

The return value of calls to `malloc()` (and `calloc()` and friends) should always be tested to ensure the operation worked as expected.

Comment: You know, it would probably be helpful to the OP if you would explain why UB is getting involved (the fact that he's not handling malloc failures).

Comment: Actually, both cases have the same UB due to failure to validate the return of `malloc()`. The first case has the bonus UB from not allocating room for the NUL.

Answer (score 0):

(1) with `strlen` but not adding 1 is definitely incorrect. If you add 1, it would have the added benefit that it also works for pointers, not just arrays.

On the other hand, (2) is preferred as long as your string is actually an array, as it results in a compile-time constant, rather than a call to `strlen` (and thus faster and smaller code). Actually a modern compiler like `gcc` can probably optimize the `strlen` out if it knows the string is constant, but it may be hard for the compiler to determine this, so I'd always use `sizeof` when possible.

Comment: In all situations where you can correctly use `sizeof`, the compiler **will** figure out that `strlen` can be optimized. So there’s simply no reason to use `sizeof` *at all*.

Comment: @Konrad: `char test[] = "bla bla \0 bla";`; `strlen(test) == 8`

Comment: @Konrad: not true. It's possible the contents of the string are variable, but always fit in a small fixed-size array. In this case, `strlen` **cannot** be optimized out, but allocating a fixed-size object the same size as the array is always suitable.

Comment: @pmg: that’s a completely different use-case. We were (implicitly) talking about zero-delimited strings here, otherwise `strlen` would make no sense at all. When dealing with raw data that may contain null bytes, treating that data as a (zero-delimited) string is obviously a bug.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a critical path, `sizeof` has advantage over `strlen` as it has an O(1) complexity which can save CPU cycles.

Comment: sizeof is computed at compile time and at every place sizeof is replaced by an integer as computed by compiler for that. There is no more run time computation for sizeof however for strlen the complete string is parsed once.