# C++(Visual Studio 2012): Copying a function's parameter char* to a dynamically allocated one

Tags: char, malloc, strcpy

I have this structure defined and a class in my project. It is a class that holds id numbers generated by GetIdUsingThisString(char *), which is a function that loads a texture file into GPU and returns an id(OpenGL).

The problem is, when I try to read a specific file, the program crashes. When I run this program in VS with debugging it works fine, but running .exe crashes the program(or running without debugging from MSVS).  By using just-n-time debugger I have found out that, for num of that specific file, Master[num].name actually contains "\x5" added(concatenation) at the end of the file path, and this is only generated for this one file. Nothing out of this method could do it, and I also use this type of slash / in paths, not \ .

```
struct WIndex{
    char* name;
    int id;
};

class Test_Class
{
public:    
    Test_Class(void);
    int AddTex(char* path);
    struct WIndex* Master;
    TextureClass* tex;
    //some other stuff...
};
```

Constructor:

```
Test_Class::Test_Class(void)
{
    num=0;
    Master=(WIndex*)malloc(1*sizeof(WIndex));

    Master[0].name=(char*)malloc(strlen("Default")*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Master[0].name,"Default");
    Master[0].id=GetIdUsingThisString(Master[0].name);
}
```

Adding a new texture:(The bug)

```
int Test_Class::AddTex(char* path)
{
    num++;
    Master=(WIndex*)realloc(Master,(num+1)*sizeof(WIndex));

    Master[num].name=(char*)malloc(strlen(path)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(Master[num].name,path);<---HERE

    Master[num].id=GetIdUsingThisString(path);
    return Master[num].id;
}
```

At runtime, calling AddTex with this file would have path with the right value, while Master[num].name will show this modified value after strcpy(added "\x5").

**Question:**
Is there something wrong with copying(strcpy) to a dynamically allocated string? If i use char name[255] as a part of the WIndex structure, everything works fine.

More info: 
 This exact file is called "flat blanc.tga". If I put it in a folder where I intended it to be, fread in GetIdUsingThisString throws corrupted heap errors. If I put it in a different folder it is ok. If I change it's name to anything else, it's ok again. If I put a different file and give it that same name, it is ok too(**!!!**). I need the program to be bug free of this kind of things because I won't know which textures will be loaded(if I knew I could simply replace them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Master[num].name=(char*)malloc(strlen(path)*sizeof(char));
```

Should be

```
Master[num].name=(char*)malloc( (strlen(path)+1) * sizeof(char));
```

There was not place for the terminating NULL character

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/:

> Copies the C string pointed by source into the array pointed by
>   destination, **including the terminating null character** (and
>   stopping at that point).

The same happens here:

```
Master[0].name=(char*)malloc(strlen("Default")*sizeof(char));
strcpy(Master[0].name,"Default");
```

Comment: You are right about the size, it's just that I have somehow built the exe with your suggestion of the size and still got an error(obviously with something else), then I mistakenly assumed that it wasn't what I was supposed to do so I returned it to the bad size. I just don't see why didn't VS throw any errors when in debugging mode, and why does it only fail for this one file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definitions (below) - you should use strlen(string)+1 for malloc.

`A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself).`

`The strcpy() function shall copy the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null byte)`

- Also see discussions in [How to allocate the array before calling strcpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695263/should-i-use-strlen-or-sizeof-with-malloc-for-a-string)