# how to copy stuff from getenv()?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a copy of path, here is what I have:

```
char *path = getenv("PATH");
char *path_copy;
path_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(path));
memcpy(path_copy, path, sizeof(path));
```

and now path is: /soft/linux/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin: (etc)
but path_copy is: /soft/li

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sizeof(path)` is the size of pointer. Use `strcpy` and friends. In your case `strdup` is the ideal one (yet non-standard)

Comment: if you must use malloc then malloc(strlen(path)+1).  Also memcpy the same, with the +1, for the terminating NULL

Comment: Or use `snprintf` or even better `asprintf`

Comment: As soon as I can find what I'm sure is one of *many* duplicates I'm deleting that answer =P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937181/sizeof-vs-strlen, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695263/how-to-allocate-the-array-before-calling-strcpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533519/newbie-questions-about-malloc-and-sizeof

Comment: Thanks, @IljaEverilä. The last one looks like a winner